# Close the app when back button clicked twice

Tags: java, android, button

My Activity flow looked like this

```
LogIn Activity-> Activity A(Main Page)->Activity B-> Activity C
```

When button in C is clicked, it will intent to A.

When back button in A is pressed twice,it should close the app.

```
  boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
     public void onBackPressed(){
            if(doubleBackToExitPressedOnce)
            {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            }

            this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
                    Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); // close app code
                    a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(a);
                }
            },2000);
```

Problem :

> when I press the button one times, it will display `Please click BACK
>   again to exit`, and then it will close the app automatically even I
>   didn't clicked the button twice.
>
> If I click the button twice, it will back to LogIn Activity. What is
>   the correct way to write ? Thanks

**Edit**

If I remove the `intent`

```
 public void onBackPressed(){
        if(doubleBackToExitPressedOnce)
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

            }
        },2000);


    }
```

When double click the back button, it will back to Activity C again.

Comment: Why is that intent there? remove the intent code. Call finish instead of super and it should be fine

Comment: @PedroOliveira I don't want to use `finish()`. I have back button in all activity and I would like to back to previous activity.

Comment: Then keep the super. But remove the intent logic

Comment: @PedroOliveira check my post again

Comment: You said you would like to get to "previous activity". If you want to go from C to A you have to stop B too. you can use results to finish the activity B if you came from C.backPress

Comment: @PedroOliveira strange. App will not be closed if I remove the intent code. I want when double click in Activity A, it will close the app without return to LogIn Activity or Activity C

Comment: " I want when double click in Activity A, it will close the app" then in Activity A call `finishAffinaty();` when you are on A.doubleBackPress :)

Comment: @PedroOliveira Cannot resolved finishAffinaty();

Comment: `finishAffinity` -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()

Comment: @PedroOliveira THANKS !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe just use `long lastTimePressed=0L;` and store in it `System.currentTimeMillis();` and `if(System.currentTimeMillis()-lastTimePressed>2000) finish();`

2000 for `Toast.Length_SHORT`, 3500 for `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`

```
long lastTimePressed=0L;

@Override
public void onBackPressed (){
    if(System.currentTimeMillis()-lastTimePressed>2000) //short Toast duration, now should be faded out
        finish();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    lastTimePressed=System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

don't start new `Activity` (or maybe? if you have implemented `singleTask` or `singleTop` or `noHistory`, but I doubt). `finish();` and `super.onBackPressed();` do the same practially. possibility for override `onBackPressed` is added later in API5, because its simply usefull :)

ohh, now I see your edit and everything is clear. Don't start your Activities with `startActivity`, but with `startActivityForResult`. Implement also `onActivityResult` ([check out here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)). When you use

```
private static final int MY_RESULT_IS_KILL_MY_APP=4573; //random

setResult(MY_RESULT_IS_KILL_MY_APP);
finish();
```

and `Activity` below receives that in own `onActivityResult` it should also set this result and call `finish();`. This way stack of Activities clean away and entire Application will exit. Without setting this static result `finish();` will finish only current `Activity`

Comment: where should I add the Toast ?

Comment: thanaks for your answer, I use @Predro answer. The `finishAffinity` did the tricks :)

Comment: true, didn't know that method. way better :) noted for future use!

Comment: Thanks for your help between. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Finish LogIn Activity Before opening Activity A. that's it.

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

 @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if(doubleBackToExitPressedOnce)
            {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            }

            this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            },2000);
        }
```

Comment: you both don't understand that once pressed back will call `new Handler().post(...` and never cancel it, so even first one and only press will close `MainActivity` after 2 secs

Comment: i understand what you want buddy, when you start activity A from LogIn Activity be sure to close LogInActivity by calling LogInActivity.this.finish();

Comment: But the problem is when I click the back button in A, it will return to Activity C again and I don't want to have `finish()` in B and C because I have a back button on both activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
    super.onBackPressed();
    return;
}

this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
    }
 }, 2000);
}
```